# HP EliteBook 8540w doesn't start with GPT disc attached

Tags: external-hard-drive, freeze, gpt, hp-elitebook

I have an HP EliteBook 8540w but since I attached a 4 TB external GPT disc drive, it does not start anymore.
(It freezes during the BIOS startup.)

When I detach the disc, everything works fine.

I already have disabled USB boot in the BIOS settings, but it still doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're trying to boot from the disk, the obvious workaround is to disconnect the disk until your OS has booted, then plug it in. This may be awkward, but it should work.

You might try setting the "active/boot" flag on the 0xEE "partition" in the MBR. You can do this with Linux's `fdisk` utility -- but do *not* use `parted` or any other libparted-based tool. I'm not sure what to suggest using if you're running Windows, but in a pinch you could use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) or some other Linux emergency disc to run Linux's `fdisk`. Some buggy BIOSes want to see a "boot/active" flag set or they won't boot from a disk. Normally this only affects boot disks, but it's conceivable that your BIOS is affected by this even on a non-boot disk. There are some additional obscure suggestions on the [gdisk Web site.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html)

If that doesn't help, you might try posting detailed information about the partitions on the disk. The output of `gdisk -l` on the disk would provide this information. (Note that's `gdisk`, not the `fdisk` I recommended earlier.) You could also try the `v` option within `gdisk`, to verify the GPT data structures. A BIOS probably wouldn't look at this, but if your firmware is actually an EFI, it might be doing so, and get hung up on a GPT error.

Another thing you might try is to look for a firmware update for your computer. It's conceivable that this is a known bug that's been fixed by such an update.

One final point: Some external disks use 4096-byte logical sectors. Such disks can be up to 16TiB in size and still use MBR. If you've got such a disk, switching from GPT to MBR is an option. You can do this losslessly with `gdisk` and with some commercial Windows tools. If you're booting anything from the disk, though, this will require re-installing your boot loader.

Comment: well... I think I'm just going to connect the disc whenever I need it...